# Setting read-only fields in unit test

Tags: apex, unit-test

How can I fake setting some read-only fields in a unit test? I would like to avoid saving data...

```
Account testAccount = new Account(name = "Foobar", id = generateId(Account.sobjectType));
Lead testLead = new Lead(
  name = "Buzbar", 
  id = generateId(Lead.sobjectType),
  isConverted = true,
  convertedAccount = testAccount  // Field is not writeable: ConvertedAccount
);
```

I get this error:

> Field is not writeable: ConvertedAccount.

Also, I tried using `testLead.putSObject('ConvertedAccount', testAccount);` but that fails at runtime.

How can I mock this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it much easier if I created my own proxy/wrapper Apex class than using the built in `Lead` class. That way I could manipulate the instance as I saw fit instead of creating many objects to test with.

Answer (score 5):

You can use JSON and deserialization:

```
String payload = '{"ConvertedAccountId": "001000000000000"}';
Lead record = (Lead)JSON.deserialize(payload, Lead.class);
system.assertNotEquals(null, record.ConvertedAccountId);
```

If you wanted to instead set the name pointing reference, you would need to specify an object payload instead:

```
String payload = '{"ConvertedAccount": {"Id": "001000000000000"}}';
Lead record = (Lead)JSON.deserialize(payload, Lead.class);
system.assertNotEquals(null, record.ConvertedAccount);
```

All of this payload building might be easier (and certainly cleaner) if you serialize a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
String payload = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{
    'ConvertedAccount' => new Account(Id='001'.rightPad(15, '0'))
});
```

Comment: the isConverted works fine. i just need the sobjects for account, contact, and opportunity set.

Comment: @DanielA.White Same concept still applies.

Comment: how can i get the account details into the lead object - like name for instance?

Comment: You could set fields on `record` just like if you constructed it (`record.Name = 'abc';`). Or you could add it to the `payload`.

Comment: hm k. thx i'll give this a test...

Comment: Ok so i'm able to assign the `ConvertedAccountId`, but `ConvertedAccount` is null. I've tried nesting it and no luck there.

Comment: @DanielA.White Again, it's still the same concept. See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an interface and dependency injection to create a FieldReader class that accepts mock values in these fields:

- [How to mock formulas and read-only fields in Apex tests?](https://matheusdev.medium.com/how-to-mock-formulas-and-non-writable-relationships-in-apex-2aca1595aab4)
- [Repository on Github: Mock Field Reader](https://github.com/gitmatheus/MockFieldReader).